# Flutter does not find Pre-installed Android SDK

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

> C:\Users\joy bank> flutter doctor
>   Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
>   [✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.1.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.251],
>   [X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
>          x Unable to locate Android SDK.
>             Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.htm
>              On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components
>             (or visit https://flutterdo/setuprnandroid-setup for detailed instructions
>             If Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set ANDROID_HOME to
>             You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.
>
> [!] Android Studio (not installed)
>   [!] Connected device
>       ! No devices available
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
>
> C:\Users\joy bank>flutter
>
> C:\Users\joy bank>

Screenshot: http://www5.0zz0.com/2019/02/04/04/122309022.jpeg

As the picture above shows:

- After I installed flutter sdk, and set environment variables
- Run flutter doctor, at first it's working
- But after a while it's not working any more, I can't use any flutter command

I have tried many different versions of sdk and reinstall my os "windows 10".

What is the wrong here please?

Comment: There's no thing to copy and paste when click enter it's loading and then nothing

Answer (score 0):

By your error I can see Android SDK is not installed. Reinstall Android SDK, and make sure you update your path variable.

Comment: Problem is i can't run flutter doctor anymore even after installing Android sdk

Answer (score 0):

I need some more information for this question

1. The Environment Variables you have set. (PATH, ANDROID_HOME)
2. The location of the installed Android SDK

Please specify your environment status.